# Gradle Script plugin debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

I can debug build.gradle script, but it seems IDE can't properly wire into script plugins of Gradle to debug them. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.3.

Its reproducible in the below example project:
There is

- **build.gradle** containing mainTask, and
- **scriptPlugin.gradle** a script plugin with scriptPluginTask task.

[image]

[image]

And following configuration that enables Gradle script debugging in IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

Now if I run mainTask in debug mode, execution actually stops at the breakpoint set in build.gradle file in mainTask on line 5.

But if I try to debug task that is imported through script plugin, namely scriptPluginTask from scriptPlugin.gradle file then execution just runs through without stopping at the breakpoint on line 3.

**Question**

Do I need to set additional configuration options to enable debugging Gradle script plugins from IntelliJ IDEA?

Or is this feature currently not supported at all? That means if I would want to debug script plugin I would actually need to copy paste whole content to the build.gradle file itself and debug it there.

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250737

Comment: Can you check the link again? I get redirected to page caying nope can't find it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it has limited visibility. Probably it's better to create new issue on YouTrack, so developers could contact you directly.

Comment: OK created new issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-267460, waiting for the answer, thanks!